# header and int main file

Tags: c++, header

so the program is going to calculate the total mile per hour during the trip. But however my total Mile per hour for a few trips is doubling instead of staying the same. Does anyone know why is that?

this is my head (.h) file

```
class Distance
{
public:
    Distance() :
        tripMiles(0.0), tripGallons(0.0),
        totalMiles(0.0), totalGallons(0.0){}
    void addTrip(double miles, double gallons)
    {
        tripMiles = miles;
        tripGallons = gallons;
        totalMiles += miles;
        totalGallons += gallons;
    }
    double getTripMiles() const {return tripMiles;}
    double getTripGallons() const {return tripGallons;}
    double getMilesTotal() const {return totalMiles;}
    double getGallonsTotal() const {return totalGallons;}
    double getTripMPG() const {return tripMiles / tripGallons; }
    double getTotalMPG() const {return totalMiles / totalGallons; }

private:
    double tripMiles, tripGallons;
    double totalMiles, totalGallons;
};
```

and this is my main file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Distance.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Distance myDistance;
    double miles= 0.0;
    double gallons = 0.0;
    cout << "Enter miles driven (-1 to quit): ";
    cin >> miles;
    myDistance.addTrip(miles,gallons);

    while(miles != -1)
    {
        cout << "\nEnter Gallons used: ";
        cin >> gallons;
        myDistance.addTrip(miles,gallons);
        cout << "\nMPG this trip: " << myDistance.getTripMPG();
        cout << "\nTotal MPG is: " << myDistance.getTotalMPG();
        cout << "\nEnter miles driven (-1 to quit): ";
        cin >> miles;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `myDistance.addTrip(miles,gallons);` once before the loop starts, then again in the loop. This means you count the miles from the first trip twice. You should remove the first one.